# Getting error of installing .Ipa file in to my iPad

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, itunes

I developed an app and created a `.Ipa` file and sync it with my iPad1 but the problem is, I am trying to sync the same app in to my other iPad2 using iTunes.

But it is not syncing and showing an error that the `App can't be installed and installation failed!!!`.

Comment: is your iPad2 device ID in the provisioning profile? also, is your iPad2 running an older version of iOS? (the min deployment version of the app might be too high)

Comment: Hi Mike, Wat do you mean my "Provisioning profile"

Comment: provisioning profiles are what you code sign apps with to allow them to run on specified devices. open up Organizer in Xcode, select your iPad2 and if there's a big button saying "Use for development" then click it. If you don't see that, then select the devices "Provisioning Profiles" and make sure there is a valid profile there (i.e. one that isn't expired).

it may have nothing to do with profiles, but worth checking.

Comment: Someone marked this as "off topic" but this is a valid development issue.  I wish I could vote against a close request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several reasons for failed to instal in device.

1.check your provisioning profile contains device UDID of ipad2 added or not.

2.check your ipa file created properly or not.if you feel you created properly then delete the app from your first device which is having same app and instal the ipa again and check once.Then you come to know your ipa creation is correct.

3.one more reason might have take place is ipa may break accidentally.

Answer (score 0):

you can check these steps:-

1. Make sure that your iPad2 device ID is  added to your provision profile you have created in developer portal.
2. Make sure that your bundle id  in your plist is match with the  your provisioning profile bundle ID you have choose to build your project.
3. Second thing you can check if the provision profile is installed on your device on not.

Thanks,
Sandeep

Answer (score 0):

This is a free program to check an IPA file for errors, there's over 20 reasons why an IPA file will fail to install, many strange combinations in mobileprovisioning and info.plist files.

[CheckIPA](https://github.com/apperian/iOS-checkIPA)