# Distribute ipa in iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

We have developed an iPhone application. Then client wants to demo the app to his clients in iPad. When we create an ipa and try to install ipa in the iPad. We got error saying like this ipa can not be installed in ipad. Is there any workaround for that or any documentation for steps to follow?

Comment: Did you add the UDID before building the iPA?

Comment: Yes. We have added.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting error of installing .Ipa file in to my iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8737771/getting-error-of-installing-ipa-file-in-to-my-ipad)

Comment: Does your info.plist specify any required hardware, such as GPS?  Non cellular iPads don't have a GPS chipset

Answer (score 0):

There could be multiple issues

1. Device UDID is not added in your Apple developer account
2. Deployment Target in Xcode can be greater than the Device OS version
3. From Left navigation pane of Xcode click on top project title, And then on right in General section, move to Deployment Info portion, there set Devices to iPad or universal.

After verifying above points, if you still face some issue, don't hesitate to let me know.